# SSD is recognized by the fdisk and sfdisk after a secure erase operation

Tags: linux, ssd, storage

I have an SSD of type MTFDHAL800MCE from Micron technology. My system is based on Mint18 and it is installed on an HDD not the SSD. I connect to this system remotely using putty. Micron has provided a Storage Executive CLI as a tool to run specific commands on the SSDs. The links for the msecli user guide and the datasheet for my SSD is available here: [msecli-userguide](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/software/storage-executive-software/msecli/storage_executive_cli_user_guide.pdf?la=en) and [SSD-datasheet](https://datasheet4u.com/datasheet-pdf/Micron/MTFDHAL800MCE/pdf.php?id=1248509).

I used the `msecli` secure erase command, page 45 of msecli-userguide, to perform a secure erase on my NVMe SSD:

> The section above covers changing the LBA format on a given namespace,
>   which causes user data to be erased. This same command can be used to
>   perform a secure erase or cryptographic erase (where supported) on the
>   namespace. You do not need to change LBA format to perform a secure
>   erase, simply set the metadata and LBA size to the current settings.
>   WARNING: A secure erase operation removes all user data on the
>   namespace. Backup data before proceeding. Make sure to offline/unmount
>   the namespace OS device before attempting this operation.
>
> Usage:
>   msecli -N -f < namespace-ID> -m < metadata size> -g < LBA size> -j [ 1
>   (Secure Erase) | 2 (Cryptographic Erase)] -n < device-name>
>
> 1. Enter the following at the command prompt: msecli -N -f < namespace-ID> -m < metadata size> -g < LBA size> -j [ 1 | 2 ] -n < device-name>
> 2. When prompted, enter Y to proceed with the secure erase operation.
> 3. The operation begins and may take up to a few minutes to complete.

However, after an hour it failed with the error message

> the device was not found

The device was recognized by the kernel as `/dev/nvme0` prior to the secure erase operation. But after the secure erase and that error message, the NVMe SSD was no more detected by `fdisk` and `sfdisk`.

I, also, used

```
msecli -L
```

to display all devices in my system; but, the SSD was not recognized.

I rebooted the system by

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

but nothing changed. Why the SSD is no more recognized and how can I fix this?

Comment: anything in dmesg / syslog / journal at the time the device disappeared? does it show in /proc/partitions, lspci, lshw, lsmod? if it's hardware failure there isn't anything you can do. instead of a soft reboot you could also try to power cycle / cold boot if that's possible.

Comment: @frostschutz No nothing is shown about the device on pci, unfortunately.

Comment: @frostschutz Is there any method to shutdown (not restart) the remote system and then turn it on again without the need to use the power button?

Comment: Without preparation, not really possible... it's a shot in the dark anyway. If there's nothing in the logs (please check) and no other indications, you might need remote hands. Did the drive have any issues before deciding to secure erase it? In future consider using `blkdiscard` instead, it involves less risk and is usually good enough to get rid of old data on SSDs.

Comment: @frostschutz No it did not have any issues before erasing. Is there any method to shutdown (not restart) the remote system and then turn it on again without the need to use the power button?