# How to shutdown and turn on a remote system from command line

Tags: linux, shutdown, reboot

I have a Mint18 system to which I connect remotely from Windows using putty. I need to shut down the remote system and then turn it on again (Not the restart o reboot) due to the issue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571464/ssd-is-recognized-by-the-fdisk-and-sfdisk-after-a-secure-erase-operation). However, this is a remote system and I don't have any access to the power button to turn it on. I searched about the `shutdown`, `poweroff`, and `reboot` commands with their options but they seem not to do what I want. Is there any command to do this from the command line?

Comment: Short answer - No, unless you have an OOB network or serial connection to a LOM, ILOM or always powered on management port on the remote system.

Comment: @fpmurphy And to what do you consider WOL a solution for? Sure, ILO is much mor elaborate, yet the OP just asked for booting a powered of machine.

Comment: @WGRM.  Sure, WOL is another solution if you are willing accept the security issues.

Comment: I immediately thought of `RB_POWERCYCLE` (https://reviews.freebsd.org/D12777) until I read the question body and tags.

Comment: Please edit question to tell us why re-boot will not work. There may be a solution, to the problem. Even if it is impossible to do it the way that you envisage.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

You want to shut down the remote system, but won't accept a reboot. So the answer is simply **no**. Anyway, respecting the given fact, that there are almost always workarounds, the following options exist:

You system mainboard has to be able to perform `Wake On LAN` and you need to be in the local network to perform this action. If you want to do this over the internet, you need to setup a VPN connection.

If you configure your BIOS/UEFI accordingly, you can the shutdown the host remotely and start it with a wol application with acces to your lan. There are even android apps which perform this action. It just sends the reversed MAC address to power the machine. It should be selfevident, that your machine still has to be connected to power. So no switches to save money.

Comment: yes, I connect to the remote system using a VPN to be in the local network. I checked whether the motherboard supports WoL.
 It seems that it is supported and enabled. The output is: `Supports Wake-on: pumbg Wake-on: g`

Comment: So how can I use this WoL option?

Comment: https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-use-wake-on-lan-on-windows-10/

Comment: is there a way to edit bios settings from command line? because I don't know if wol is enabled in the bios or not

Comment: This is kind of sophisticated and error prone. Do it yourself.

Comment: I could not wake up the machine. I think the wol settings in the bios are not configured. Now the machine is off and I cannot do anything more :(

Comment: You said, that the machine has WoL and it was enabled. I cannNOT prevent user error. All information i gave are valid.

Comment: yes it is supported in the motherboard and I am sure I enabled it. But is mentioned that we have to enable it in the bios too but I don't have access to the remote machine's bios. I installed wakemeonlan but the machine is not turned on

Answer (score 1):

If you can get into the same network and your computer support Wake-on-Lan it's possible :).

As always arch wiki has tons of information:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN

Less technical article:
https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/

Comment: Arch Linux is always a good source. *-Echange doesn't like such comments, anyway. I don't care. :)